# How can I read all pages of an API response using aiohttp with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pagination, discord.py, aiohttp

I'm using the discord.py rewrite and aiohttp. There is very little documentation for this API, and from what I've seen, I haven't seen a "next_page" link anywhere in the response.

How do I make it so that all pages of the json response are considered when the query is executed instead of just the default first page?

Here's my current relevant code:

````
async def command(ctx, *, name):
    if not name:
        return await ctx.channel.send('Uhhhh. How am I supposed to show you info if you don\'t enter a name?')
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
            async with cs.get("https://website.items.json") as r:
                data = await r.json()
                listings = data["items"]
                for k in listings:
                    if name.lower() == k["name"].lower():
                        await ctx.channel.send("message with results and player info as ascertained in the above code")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply take the max number of pages and iterate it. The final url would be like this.

```
https://theshownation.com/mlb20/apis/items.json?page=2
```

Here is how you set up the loop

```py
for page_number in range(1,total_pages):
    url = f'https://theshownation.com/mlb20/apis/items.json?page={page_number}'
```

**EDIT:**

The full implementation is like this.

```py
@bot.command()
async def card(ctx, *, player_name):
    if not player_name:
        return await ctx.channel.send('Uhhhh. How am I supposed to show you player info if you don\'t enter a player name?')

    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
            for page_number in range(1, 20):
                async with cs.get(f"https://theshownation.com/mlb20/apis/items.json?page={page_number}") as r:
                    data = await r.json()
                    print(data["page"])
                    listings = data["items"]
                    for k in listings:
                        if player_name.lower() == k["name"].lower():
                            return await ctx.channel.send("message with results and player info as ascertained in the above code")
                            

    await ctx.send('Sorry could not find him')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've done a couple variations of that, but I must be doing something incorrectly. Using your example ```            for page_number in range(1,122):
                async with cs.get("https://theshownation.com/mlb20/apis/items.json&page=" + {page_number}) as r:``` gives me this traceback: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

Comment: It should be `async with cs.get(f"https://theshownation.com/mlb20/apis/items.json&page={page_number}") as r`

Comment: Ok, I just plugged in that suggestion. There's no traceback error anymore, but it's still only pulling from the first page of the API response. When a name is typed that is on page 77, for example, the console is printing the first page of the API response on repeat. When a name is typed that is on page one of the API response, the console is printing the first page of the API response on repeat and the bot is sending my await ctx.channel.send message to the discord channel on repeat. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see you didn't do the loop correctly. I made an edit above to show you how. Keep in mind you need to change it a bit to make it loop for `total_pages`

Comment: Thank you, I think it's getting closer. Adding the `return` statement to the send message stopped the bot from sending hundreds of messages, although now it is only sending one match when there can be multiples (of the same `player_name`). I tried a couple different versions of the loop to try to read all pages of the API response, but I still can't seem to get it to read beyond page 1. I apologize, I've been having a tough time finding applicable examples that utilize aiohttp instead of requests and when I have, I haven't been able to get them to work for this purpose.

Comment: Simply remove the `return` when the name is found it will keep looping until the end page.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so very very much. I knew it was something simple!